# What cards can give an opponent control of an Island so I can use Islandwalk on them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm working on a blue/black deck with some cards that have Islandwalk and I'm trying to find cards that can force an opponent to control an island. I have [Stormtide Leviathan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=278198) but I was looking for something less costly that can exchange one of my Islands for one of their lands or just give them an island.

Comment: Spreading seas is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an artifact that slowly turns all lands into Islands: [Quicksilver Fountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quicksilver%20Fountain). There are also a few auras that turn the enchanted land into an Island (or any type, including Island): [Convincing Mirage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Convincing%20Mirage), [Lingering Mirage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lingering%20Mirage), [Nylea's Presence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373580), [Phantasmal Terrain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phantasmal%20Terrain), [Sea's Claim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sea%27s%20claim), and [Spreading Seas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spreading%20Seas). There is also a sorcery that turns a land into an Island, [Aquitect's Will](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=142354). Some other cards that can turn lands into any basic land type, including Island, are [Mystic Compass](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mystic%20Compass), [Dream Thrush](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dream%20Thrush), [Illusionary Terrain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusionary%20Terrain), [Jinx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jinx), [Moonbow Illusionist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Moonbow%20Illusionist), [Reef Shaman](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reef%20Shaman), [Sea Snidd](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sea%20Snidd), [Shimmering Mirage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shimmering%20Mirage), and [Tideshaper Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tideshaper%20Mystic).

In addition [several creatures](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22becomes%20an%20island%22&v=card&s=cname) turn lands into Islands:

- [Dreamwinder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreamwinder) temporarily turns a land into an Island at the cost of sacrificing an Island. [Kukemssa Serpent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kukemssa%20Serpent) does the same.
- [Floodchaser](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Floodchaser) temporarily turns a land into an Island at the cost of a +1/+1 counter.
- [Sealock Monster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sealock%20Monster) permanently turns a land into an Island when it becomes monstrous.
- [Streambed Aquitects](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Streambed%20Aquitects), [Tidal Warrior](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tidal%20Warrior), and [Tundra Kavu](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tundra%20Kavu) can both tap to temporarily turn a land into an Island.

There are also cards that you can use to make an opponent control one of your Islands, including [Bazaar Trader](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bazaar%20Trader), [Donate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Donate), [Gauntlets of Chaos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gauntlets%20of%20Chaos), [Political Trickery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Political%20Trickery), [Shifting Borders](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shifting%20Borders), [Shifting Loyalties](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shifting%20Loyalties), [Sky Swallower](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sky%20Swallower), [Vedalken Plotter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vedalken%20Plotter), and [Zedruu the Greathearted](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zedruu%20the%20Greathearted). You can also use [Yavimaya Dryad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Yavimaya%20Dryad) to search for [Breeding Pool](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Breeding%20Pool) or [Tropical Island](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tropical%20Island) and put it into play under your opponent's control.

Comment: There are also some cards that exchange control of permanents, too. For instance, Vedalken Plotter or Political Trickery.

Comment: Those kinds of cards may be trickier to use for these purposes, but I'll add them

Comment: And don't forget searching up a Tropical Island or Breeding Pool with Yavimaya Dryad. :)

Comment: [Phantasmal terrain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221553)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Added, plus a few others.

Comment: This wiki page has a good list of all land-changing cards sorted by type. http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Land_changers

Comment: I didn't know about that page. I added all relevant cards from that page to my answer.

Comment: There must be a subset of phrase searches that can be performed using the advanced search features on the Gatherer that will obtain all of these cards plus some that were missed. For example, rules text contains "land is an Island" OR "land is the chosen type" OR "land is every basic land type". Those three phrases alone pick up eight of the cards in your answer. See results [here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=|[%22land%20is%20an%20Island%22]|[%22land%20is%20the%20chosen%20type%22]|[%22land%20is%20every%20basic%20land%20type%22]).

Comment: I did find many of these cards using the advanced search features of magiccards.info, but I still had to cull some lists, and that didn't find all of them. The control-changing cards were a little trickier, for example. But I'll take you up on that bet: if you can produce a single search that finds every card in this list without finding any cards that don't match the original criteria, I'll replace my whole answer with that query and an explanation of it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I like your explanation and was hoping to add to it rather than replace it. When I have more time I will try and experiment with "What are the fewest search terms that will get every single card in this answer without any false positives?"

Answer (score -3):

The ultimate troll card beckons you - [Puca's Mischief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=141996)

Comment: That card lets you exchange **nonland** permanents. What use is it in this situation?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MyTurnYet This *is* an answer to the question, albeit a very wrong and poorly explained one.